# Insert query on procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure like this

```
set @dt=now();
SET @query = CONCAT('insert into tbl_Name (Name , Created_Date , Created_By) values (?,?,?)'); 
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt using @tbl_column_value, @dt, @tbl_user_id;
END IF;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

im getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PREPARE stmt FROM @query;`?

Comment: ahh it gives syntax error